# I am trying to get stripe integrated in react native, but payment is not succeeded on stripe dashboard only intent shows up on dashboard

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe payments in react native, below is my code, When I click on checkout button, payment sheet opens up, I enter the test credit card details (4242...) and other details. but when I click on pay button, it only creates payment Intent on stripe dashboard for $20 but does not succeed , what am I missing ?

```
import {  
  useStripe,
  createToken,
  confirmPayment,  
  usePaymentSheet,
} from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import createPaymentIntent from './apis/stripeApis';


export default function PaymentScreen() {


  const {initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet} = useStripe();


  const onCheckout = async () => {
    try {
      // 1. Create a payment intent
      const response = await createPaymentIntent({
        amount: '2000',
        currency: 'usd',
      });
      if (response.error) {
        Alert.alert('Something went wrong');
        return;
      }

      // 2. Initialize the Payment sheet
      const initResponse = await initPaymentSheet({
        merchantDisplayName: 'MerchantName',
        paymentIntentClientSecret: response.data.paymentIntent,
      });
      if (initResponse.error) {
        console.log(initResponse.error);
        Alert.alert('Something went wrong');
        return;
      }
     

      // 3. Present the Payment Sheet from Stripe
      const paymentResponse = await presentPaymentSheet();
      
      if (paymentResponse.error) {
        Alert.alert(
          `Error code: ${paymentResponse.error.code}`,
          paymentResponse.error.message,
        );
        return;
      }

     
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      Alert.alert('An error occurred');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={StyleSheet.container}>
      <View style={{padding: 16}}>
        
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onCheckout}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 50}}>Checkout</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is the createPaymentIntent component

```
import axios from 'axios';

const createPaymentIntent = data => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .post('http://192.168.1.5:4002/payment-sheet', data)
      .then(function (res) {
        resolve(res);
        console.log('response', res);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

export default createPaymentIntent;
```

And this is server.js file:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(
  'MY_KEY',
);
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Test');
});

app.post('/payment-sheet', async (req, res) => {
  const {amount, currency} = req.body;
  // Use an existing Customer ID if this is a returning customer.
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create();
  const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: customer.id},
    {apiVersion: '2022-11-15'},
  );
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: currency,
    customer: customer.id,
    // payment_method_types: ['card'],
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

  res.json({
    paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
    customer: customer.id,
  });
});

app.listen(4002, () => console.log('Running on http://localhost:4002'));
```

Comment: What is your `createPaymentIntent` doing? Do you get any errors in your device or server logs? You need to share a bit more detail here.